# Modify a jQuery script to remove a function (without breaking it...)

Tags: jquery, html

I've installed a nice little jQuery mailer script that contains a required field (Subject) I don't want, and would like to remove it. First I simply removed the html, forgetting the verification and got an error. Then I tried to remove the part of the script that verifies if a Subject (a `<select>`) was chosen, but got an error, and am asking for help, now. Here's the script:

html:

```
<form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="submit.php">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
          <td width="25%" style="text-align:right;"><label for="name">Name</label></td>
          <td width="65%" style="text-align:left;"><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter]]" name="name" id="name" value="<?=$_SESSION['post']['name']?>" /></td>
          <td width="10%" id="errOffset" style="text-align:right;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align:right;"><label for="email">Email</label></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]]" name="email" id="email" value="<?=$_SESSION['post']['email']?>" /></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="subject">Subject</label></td>
          <td><select name="subject" id="subject">
            <option value="" selected="selected"> - Choose -</option>
            <option value="Question">Question</option>
            <option value="Business proposal">Business proposal</option>
            <option value="Advertisement">Advertising</option>
            <option value="Complaint">Complaint</option>
          </select>          </td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" style="text-align:right;"><label for="message">Message</label></td>
          <td><textarea name="message" id="message" class="validate[required]" cols="35" rows="5"><?=$_SESSION['post']['message']?></textarea></td>
          <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="captcha"><?=$_SESSION['n1']?> + <?=$_SESSION['n2']?> =</label></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyNumber]]" name="captcha" id="captcha" /></td>
          <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
          <input type="reset" name="button2" id="button2" value="Reset" />

          <?=$str?>          <img id="loading" src="img/ajax-load.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="loading" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </form>
```

And the script from where I'd like to remove the 'Subject' verification function:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contact-form').jqTransform();

    $("button").click(function(){

        $(".formError").hide();

    });

    var use_ajax=true;
    $.validationEngine.settings={};

    $("#contact-form").validationEngine({
        inlineValidation: false,
        promptPosition: "centerRight",
        success :  function(){use_ajax=true},
        failure : function(){use_ajax=false;}
     })

    $("#contact-form").submit(function(e){

        if(!$('#subject').val().length)
            {
            $.validationEngine.buildPrompt(".jqTransformSelectWrapper","* This field is required","error")
            return false;
        }

            if(use_ajax)
            {
                $('#loading').css('visibility','visible');
                $.post('submit.php',$(this).serialize()+'&ajax=1',

                    function(data){
                        if(parseInt(data)==-1)
                            $.validationEngine.buildPrompt("#captcha","* Wrong verification number!","error");

                        else
                        {
                            $("#contact-form").hide('slow').after('<h1>Thank you!</h1>');
                        }

                        $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
                    }

                );
            }
            e.preventDefault();
    })

});
```

I'd tried removing the area indicated in the above code. The script has an 'are you human' simple math function, and after removing the code, I got an alert stating the answer to the simple math was wrong despite the fact that it was correct.

Comment: Is it me, or is something being cut off here? Can you post your JS files to jsfiddle.net and link us to it?

Comment: @harryfino - I'm left to suspect that this is the only script required to remove what I want removed: http://jsfiddle.net/Tm9Nk/

Comment: @jli - Yeah, I get that a lot. Thing is, there are quite a few questions that I've asked that have received no answer, or, whose answer came in the form of a comment. If I can use what was posted, or even get pointed in the right direction in the form of an answer, I accept.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you're displaying here, all you should need to do is remove the code block for the subject test:

```
if(!$('#subject').val().length) {
    $.validationEngine.buildPrompt(".jqTransformSelectWrapper","* This field is required","error")
    return false;
}
```

If you're getting an error after you do that, it's probably because there is some more validation on the server side. Without your `submit.php` file, it's impossible for us to know. But your issue seems to be that the file is returning `data: -1` and getting caught in this block:

```
function(data) {
    if (parseInt(data) == -1)
        $.validationEngine.buildPrompt("#captcha","* Wrong verification number!","error");
```

If you post your submit code, we can probably help you more.